# Mistake in Hatcher

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

A $1$-dimensional cell complex, $X$, is called a $\textit{graph}$.  A subset of $X$ is closed iff its intersection with the closure $\overline{e_\alpha}$ of each edge $e_{\alpha}$ ($1$-dimensional cell) is closed in $\overline{e_\alpha}$.  So every sequence in $X$ of points belonging to the interiors of disjoint edges is closed and doesn't converge.  This is correct but then Hatcher makes the following incorrect claim.  "This cell complex topology cannot be a metric topology if $X$ contains a vertex that is a common vertex of infinitely many edges; otherwise take a sequence of points in the disjoint interiors of these edges that gets closer and closer to the common vertex."  The common vertex is not in the closure of this sequence and hence there is no contradiction with the fact that, in a metric space, every point in the closure of a set is the limit of a sequence of points in the interior of the set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hatcher's point is correct. Suppose $\alpha$ is a vertex common to infinitely many edges $E_i$ ($i\in\mathbb{N}$), and suppose $d$ were a metric on $X$ which induced the given topology. Let $x_i$ be a point on $E_i$ with $d(x_i, \alpha)<2^{-i}$.

On the one hand, we know by the definition of the topology on $X$ that $\{x_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is closed, and so $\alpha$ **is not** a limit point of $\{x_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$. On the other hand, for every $\epsilon>0$ there is some $i\in\mathbb{N}$ with $d(x_i, \alpha)<\epsilon$, so $\alpha$ **is** a limit point of $\{x_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

This gives us a contradiction, and so our original assumption - that $X$ is metrizable - was wrong.

Comment: But the sequence of points is closed and doesn't contain $\alpha$.  How do you reconcile this?

Comment: @SihOASHoihd That's exactly the point. Since that sequence of points is closed and doesn't contain $\alpha$, we get a **contradiction** with the assumption that $d$ existed.

Comment: @SihOASHoihd I've edited to clarify this point.

Comment: Why do you think he mentioned the part about the sequence also not converging then?

Comment: @SihOASHoihd I don't understand. The **whole point** is that the sequence both does and does not converge to the relevant point, if we assume metrizability, and so $X$ is not metrizable.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm inclined to believe this now.  Thanks

Comment: Whats confusing is that he mentions closure and convergence, and so you think both are necessary to his argument.  At first it seems like maybe the metric topology is something intuitive and hence I cant just take a sequence that gets "closer and closer" to the vertex

Comment: @SihOASHoihd I mean, both are necessary to his argument. Under the assumption that $X$ is metrizable we show that convergence and closure do **not** line up as they would have to, and so we conclude that $X$ is not metrizable.

Comment: How do you know that such a sequence exists.  Why cant every point within $1/n$ of $\alpha$ belongs to the same edge?

Comment: I meant to write "unintuitive" by the way.

Comment: @SihOASHoihd Think about what happens when you restrict the metric to a given $E_i$. You have to get something homeomorphic to $[0,1]$.

Comment: Good point.  But it seems like your argument is that $\alpha$ must be a limit of this sequence and hence belongs to the closure, which is impossible since $\alpha$ is not in this set.  But convergence implies belongs-to-closure in every topology.  So we only use the metric topology to create the sequence

Comment: So the fact that the sequence doesn't converge in the weak topology is not used.  Which is technically consistent with what he writes, but I find it misleading.

Comment: @SihOASHoihd No, it absolutely **is** used. That's what drives the contradiction: that it doesn't converge in the weak topology, but it would have to converge according to a hypothetical metrization of the space.

Answer (score 2):

Hatcher is correct. The contradiction is that in the CW topology no such sequence of points in the interior of distinct edges converges, but if we had a metric topology we could pick a point on the interior of the nth edge that was distance $1/n$ away from the common vertex. Since the distance between the nth point and the common vertex goes to 0, this converges which contradicts our earlier statement.